# What does text before selectors in css mean?

Tags: css

Apologies for the beginner css question but it's rather difficult to find an answer for this.
I'm looking at the duckett book for html and css and it has a couple of selector syntax confusing to me.

```css
table.one{}    
input#web{}
```

I thought that the `.x` indicates that `x` is a class selector and similarly that `#x` indicates that `x` is an id selector but why did the author choose to put text before these? He didn't give an explanation as far as I can tell.

Comment: it's saying table.one{} is selecting a table with the class .one - if table wasn't there it would select any element with a class of .one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table.one` matches all `table` elements which have class `one`.

`input#web` matches the `input` element which has id `web`.

This kind of selector is called "Type selector". You can read these resources:

- [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#type-selectors)
- [Selectors Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#type-selectors)
- [Selectors Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#type-selectors)
- [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors)

Comment: @user3813774 `input` selector matches all `input` elements.

Answer (score 1):

1. `table.one{}`
   '[element type].[css class name]{}
2. `input#web{}`
   '[element type]#[id attribute]{}

When an element type is specified, that means that definition will only work for that element type.

`table.myCss{}` for the  Element, when `class='myCss'` then apply the css. Don't apply this CSS to `<span class='myCss'>` or any other element type.

Here is a link to the official specifications page for CSS3. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

The use of `table` and `input` in front of their respective classes / IDs reference the type of element in the markup. For example:

```
table.one {
  ..
}
```

References a table with class "one" (in code: `<table class="one">`). This way, if the author has another element with class "one" (example: `<div class="one">`), the div is not affected by the rule of `table.one`.

Same idea for `input#web`, except the selector is targeted towards `input` tags with ID of "web" (`<input id="web">`)

Some additional reading from W3 may be of some help (it's from CSS2, but the main points are still present): http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/uWkYL/

Answer (score 0):

Let me break it down:

`table.one` means, look for a tag with the name `table`, which also has the class `one`
`input#web` similarly means: look for an element with the name `input` and the id of `web`

In some cases, these selectors might not be necessary, especially on IDs, since they are supposed to be unique, as opposed to classes, which are reasuable. The usage of element names with classes, however, can help you make different elements look different than others, for example, if you want to center text and a div, you might only want to use one class for both, but since `<div>` elements are block level, they can't be center like text by default.

```
div.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
p.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="x" ... >
<div class="x" ... ></div>
```

So now we have:

```
.x {} // To select both

input.x {} // To select just the input with class "x"

div.x {} // To select just the div with class "x"
```

This could be used to just make it more clear for what element the styles are for. Or to limit the elements affected.

Similarly we can do this with element ids.

```
<input id="a" ... >
<div id="b" ... ></div>
```

So we can write simply `#a`. Or we can write `input#a`. Currently these are equivalent.

With the div we would have either `#b` or `div#b`.